# How do I get the book title with a specific id using linqjs

Tags: javascript, jquery, jslinq

I have a JavaScript array with objects in it which contain an id, book title usw,  I need to search it and get the title with a given id preferable with linqjs.

Example:

"213-46-8915" : id
"The Busy Executive's Database Guid" : Title

```
<script>
   var books = [];
   books.push(["213-46-8915" , "The Busy Executive's Database Guid",19.9900,2]);
   books.push(["211-44-2314" , "The Busy Executive's Database Guid",14.4100,5]);
</script>
```

My try:

```
var filtered = Enumerable
                .From(books)
                .Where(function (x) {return x.contains(id);})
                .Select(function (x) {return x;})
                .ToArray()
```

Comment: I think you did not mean to select C#'s linq but [jslinq](https://jslinq.codeplex.com/) as your tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://jslinq.codeplex.com/), you have to call `JSLINQ(array)` first.

So, for your example. This should work. Also, I converted your array to an object

```
var books = [];
books.push({
    id: "213-46-8915",
    title: "The Busy Executive's Database Guid",
    price: 19.9900,
    quantity: 2
});

var filtered = JSLINQ(books)
               .Where(function(item) { return item.id == "213-46-8915"; })
               .Select(function(item) { return item; });

console.log(filtered.id); //213-46-8915
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do it with plain JavaScript very simply. here is the code which returns an array of array of your books filtered by id.

```js
var books = [];
books.push(["213-46-8915" , "The Busy Executive's Database Guid",19.9900,2]);
books.push(["211-44-2314" , "The Busy Executive's Database Guid",14.4100,5]);
var id = '211-44-2314';
var result = books.filter(function(b){ return b[0]==id; });
console.log(result);
```